# How do I map a model with nested properties to a flat Dto?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dto, convention-over-configur

I'm trying to create a mapping from our entity models to a Dto but I'm failing everytime in trying to create the mapping.

I have two domain classes. This is a simplification of our model (`Device` for instance has a lot more properties that represent a bunch of different things):

```
class Device
{
    public int Name {get; set;}
}

class DeviceAccessToken
{
    public Device Device {get; set;}
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public string Secret {get; set;}
}
```

I then want to map `DeviceAccessToken` instances to this `DeviceDto` (also simplified, it has most of the fields present in the original `Device` model):

```
class DeviceDto
{
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public string Secret {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to create this mapping without explicitly specifying all fields of the `Device` domain model in the mapping?

This is effectively what I want, represented by an AutoMapper profile:

```
class DeviceMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<DeviceAccessToken, DeviceDto>();

        this.CreateMap<Device, DeviceDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Key, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Secret, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

The `.ForAllMembers` call was a failed attempt to make this work, it must not function like I envisioned it.

I understand I could do this by specifying every property of the `Device` in the `DeviceAccessToken->DeviceDto` mapping, but it would be a nightmare and very redundant since the names are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Is there a way to create this mapping without explicitly specifying all fields of the Device domain model in the mapping?"*

Yes, you can use the naming conventions in your Dto object and this would prevent you having to enter them in the create map.

As an example:

Your values Key and Secret exist in `DeviceAccessToken` and `DeviceDto` they will not need to be mapped.
As `Device` is a nested object your dto can use the convention of `DeviceName`.

**Example:**

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;

class Device
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class DeviceAccessToken
{
    public Device Device {get; set;}
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public string Secret {get; set;}
}

class DeviceDto
{
    public string DeviceName {get; set;}
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public string Secret {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {

        // Configure AutoMapper
        Mapper.CreateMap<DeviceAccessToken, DeviceDto>();       

        var dat = new DeviceAccessToken { Device = new Device { Name = "Dev Name" }, Key = "Key", Secret = "Secret" };

        var dto = Mapper.Map<DeviceDto>(dat);

        Console.WriteLine(dto.DeviceName);
        Console.WriteLine(dto.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(dto.Secret);
    }
}
```

**[Working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UcbKHw)**

Comment: A little after I posted the question I found [this article](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) that explains this convention you talk about, and for now I decided to use it. But would there be a way to, also by convention, make automapper recognize the properties without having to prefix them with the nested property name? In my case, I had to create two very similar Dtos because one of them needed to have this convention, while the other did not. In some places, I need to map a `Device` directly to a `DeviceDto`, and that would make lots of things simpler on my end.

Comment: @julealgon Hi, I know what you mean but it seems different from the original question. I would create a new question, you will get more people trying to answer it. I have used the INamingConvention to change the conventions before, that might be something you could use. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/d6eaf7025932ebedccbf8c339a155e9f4ae5c5d8/src/AutoMapper/INamingConvention.cs